# How to get whole .msg attachment of an email to file system using java mail API

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have an email client receives mail from outlook. 
Scenario: Sending a mail from outlook with .msg as attachment.

I am unable to get that .msg as an attached file (as like other files which comes as attachments).

I want to just take and store that .msg attachment as a file only.

Can any one please let us know any solution to this.?

Thanks.

Comment: Show your code that saves "other files" but fails for `.msg`

Comment: What do you mean by "I am unable to get that .msg as an attached file"?

Comment: @MauricePerry, i mean when .msg file attachment bodyPart.getFileName() gives null value!